# Is AES 128 Crypto (Cipher) logic is there in Kotlin Multi Platform (KMM)?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I found AES encryption logic in Kotlin by using JavaX libraries. Since it's specific to java (Android) so it's not executing for iOS.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

object Crypto {

    fun calculateHash(data: ByteArray, key: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher: Cipher
        var encrypted = ByteArray(16)

        try {
            val secretKeyEcb: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeyEcb)
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data, 0, 16)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return encrypted.copyOf(8)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the above code in iOS or in KMM ?

Comment: There is a ton o questions about AES encryption on iOS. What exactly is giving you problems?

Comment: With Above mention code, while I am running in the KMM project (compileKotlinIosArm64 ), It says " Unresolved reference: javax "

So, I need the above logic in iOS or in KMM

Comment: @Sulthan the problem seems to be to find a way to write this encryption (or at least adapters) in multiplatform Kotlin code. And to be frank I haven't seen any duplicates so far

Comment: @Joffrey As with every multiplatform framework, sometimes you need platform-specific code.

Comment: @Sulthan it still doesn't hurt to ask whether someone wrote a KMM library for it, that's why I see nothing wrong with this question

Answer (score 5):

The Kotlin multiplatform is a new technology, and it lacks many libraries.

You will not be able to run java code on iOS, so using `Cipher` in the common code will not work.

When writing an application you will often encounter a similar problem, and the solution is always the same: create an interface class and implement it for each of the platforms.

`commomMain/Crypto.kt`

```
expect object Crypto {
    fun calculateHash(data: ByteArray, key: ByteArray): ByteArray
}
```

On android part you can use `Cipher` easily:

`androidMain/Crypto.kt`

```
actual object Crypto {
    fun calculateHash(data: ByteArray, key: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher: Cipher
        var encrypted = ByteArray(16)

        try {
            val secretKeyEcb: SecretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeyEcb)
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data, 0, 16)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return encrypted.copyOf(8)
    }
}
```

And to implement the `iosCommon` part, you need to look for an iOS solution to your problem. I advise you to look for an Objective C solution, because kotlin generates its files based on the headers of that language, so such a solution will be easier to implement than a Swift solution.

The first one I came across was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446667/3585796) and I started working with it.

You can try searching on github to see if someone has already implemented it. I try key classes from iOS and kotlin filtering, usually the number of results is minimal, if you are lucky you will find what you need.

In your case, I was lucky enough to find [this code](https://github.com/metrodroid/metrodroid/blob/aba6f72c2f6b8ddbe0d73dc0b1adbcd7248aeb32/src/iOSMain/kotlin/au/id/micolous/metrodroid/util/Aes.kt). That's the only search result for `CCCrypt` + kotlin language=). I combined it with [obj-c answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446667/3585796). This doesn't looks exactly like your `Cipher` code, you also taking only first 8 bytes for some reason. But you should get the idea:

```
actual object Crypto {
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun calculateHash(data: ByteArray, key: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        if (!listOf(
                kCCKeySizeAES128,
                kCCKeySizeAES192,
                kCCKeySizeAES256,
            ).contains(key.count().toUInt())
        ) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Invalid key length ${key.count()}")
        }
        val ivLength = kCCBlockSizeAES128
        val output = ByteArray(
            size = ivLength.toInt() * 2 + data.size
        ) { 0.toByte() }
        val outputSize = ULongArray(1) { 0u }
        key.usePinned { keyPinned ->
            data.usePinned { inputPinned ->
                output.usePinned { outputPinned ->
                    outputSize.usePinned { outputSizePinned ->
                        val rcbStatus = SecRandomCopyBytes(
                            kSecRandomDefault,
                            ivLength.toULong(),
                            outputPinned.addressOf(0)
                        )
                        if (rcbStatus != kCCSuccess) {
                            throw IllegalStateException("calculateHash rcbStatus $rcbStatus")
                        }
                        val ccStatus = CCCrypt(
                            op = kCCEncrypt,
                            alg = kCCAlgorithmAES,
                            options = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                            key = keyPinned.addressOf(0),
                            keyLength = key.size.toULong(),
                            iv = outputPinned.addressOf(0),
                            dataIn = inputPinned.addressOf(0),
                            dataInLength = data.size.toULong(),
                            dataOut = outputPinned.addressOf(ivLength.toInt()),
                            dataOutAvailable = output.size.toULong() - ivLength,
                            dataOutMoved = outputSizePinned.addressOf(0),
                        )
                        if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
                            throw IllegalStateException("calculateHash ccStatus $ccStatus")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return output.copyOf((outputSize.first() + ivLength).toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use the moder `AES` from `CryptoKit` framework, however it supports only `GCM` mode. Ideally, `GCM` should be used on both platforms as it's safer anyway.

Comment: @Sulthan If I am not mistaken, CryptoKit is pure swift, which makes it impossible to use from KMM

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your input's @PhilipDukhov and Sulthan. Our codebase is not in Objective C. I will find similar swift logic.

Comment: @mittapallihareesh if you wanna use it from the common main, you need to translate it to kotlin. That's what I did. It doesn't matter which language do you use in your project, in kolin part you can only interact with code translated from ObjC(system libraries or external frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [krypto](https://github.com/korlibs/korge/tree/main/krypto) or [libsodum wrapper](https://github.com/ionspin/kotlin-multiplatform-libsodium) libraries.

For example, with krypto library you can easily implement AES 128 in commanMain module by using these functions:

```
implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto:${Version.krypto}")



AES.encryptAes128Cbc(dataByteArray, keyByteArray, Padding.NoPadding)
AES.decryptAes128Cbc(dataByteArray, keyByteArray, Padding.ANSIX923Padding)
```